# How can i compare files names in python?

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I'm getting tired of renaming every episode with its subtitle (i have 100+)

How can I compare the 2 files if they have the same episode number in their name, after that I want it to replace the subtitle to the episode name

I tried to do it my self, I successfully managed to change the name(easy), but the comparison part is what I'm missing.

Thank you.

***edited:***

The files names would be like this;

(Episode): [PuyaSubs!] Banana Fish - 12 [1080p].mkv

(Subtitle): Banana Fish - 12.ass

what i came up so far:

```
import os
old_file = os.path.join(r"D:\Downloads\Media\Anime\[PuyaSubs!] Banana Fish [1080p][Batch]\Banana Fish - 12.ass", "Banana Fish - 12.ass")
new_file = os.path.join(r"D:\Downloads\Media\Anime\[PuyaSubs!] Banana Fish [1080p][Batch]\Banana Fish - 12.ass", "[PuyaSubs!] Banana Fish - 12 [1080p][2ECC9207].ass")
os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

this will only change the name, but it's not automated and I will have to do it for every subtitle file manually.

Comment: Please show us what you have so far so we can help you figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Give an example of how the 2 files are looking like?

Comment: The first file (the anime episode): [PuyaSubs!] Banana Fish - 01 [1080p][EBD2A650].mkv    the second (subtitle): Banana Fish - 11 .ass

Comment: You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) (regular expressions) to split the filename into parts, e.g. the show-name and the episode number and then operate on those.

Comment: OF COURSE, the subtitle of the above episode would look like this `Banana Fish - 01 .ass `.. right?

Comment: The episode has `01` in the name and the subtitle has `11` - why are they matched up?

Comment: I edited the Q with more details, thank you @aaaakshat & anwarvic

Comment: @AlexHall my mistake, I meant Banana Fish - 01.ass

Comment: (@Anwarvic) Edited with more details, thank you

Comment: @LukasKoestler looks like i can make something out of it, i will let you updated. thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I looked at this is like so:

**How I Implemented This:**

1. First get the list of all files in your directory by using `os.listdir`
2. Next we run through each file and if it contains `.ass` suffix (that means it's a subtitle file)
3. Then we look through the entire files directory to see whether there is a movie that matches to the subtitle file. We do this in the `try` statement and this allows us to break through the for loop so that we don't get any errors.
4. Lastly we just have to rename the subtitle file name, and for this we use `os.rename`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, re

def fixMySubtitles(mediaFolderPath):
    # Lists all the files in the folder
    files = os.listdir(mediaFolderPath)

    # Loops through every single file in the directory
    for file in files:
        # In the beginning we set both names to "" since we don't know what they are yet.
        movie = ""
        subtitle = ""

        # If searches the current file name to see if it ends in .ass
        if re.search(r'\.ass', file):
            # This removes the .ass part from the subtitle name
            subtitle = re.search(r'(.*).ass', file).group(1)

            # This chunk matches the subtitle file to the movie file
            movie = [movie for movie in files if subtitle in movie]
            movie = [movie for movie in movie if '.mkv' in movie]
            movie = "".join(movie)

            # Now we try to get the movie without the .mkv part
            try:
                movie = re.search(r'(.*).mkv', movie).group(1)
            except:
                print("Movie not found error for subtitle '%s'" % (file))
                break

            # Lastly we can set the path of the new subtitle file
            newPath = os.path.join(mediaFolderPath, "%s.ass" % (movie))

            # And if the movie variable has a value then we can rename
            if movie:
                os.rename(os.path.join(mediaFolderPath, file), newPath)

    print("I have fixed your subtitles!")
```

**How To Run This**

I'm actually on a Mac right now, however this should still work on windows.

1. When running this you will need a python file with the code in it.
2. Once you have this code ready inside, you will need to actually call the method since right now we have used `def` to create the function (function/method are used interchangeably) however we actually aren't running the function anywhere
3. At the bottom of your code add a line that says
   `fixMySubtitles("[DIRECTORY OF FOLDER WITH MEDIA]")` and replace `[DIRECTORY OF FOLDER...]` with the path to your folder
4. Finally you should be able to run the file with 
   `python.exe [PATH TO PYTHON FILE]`

For reference, this is the exact code I have in my file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, re

def fixMySubtitles(mediaFolderPath):
    files = os.listdir(mediaFolderPath)

    for file in files:
        movie = ""
        subtitle = ""
        if re.search(r'\.ass', file):
            subtitle = re.search(r'(.*).ass', file).group(1)
            movie = [movie for movie in files if subtitle in movie]
            movie = [movie for movie in movie if '.mkv' in movie]
            movie = "".join(movie)
            try:
                movie = re.search(r'(.*).mkv', movie).group(1)
            except:
                print("Movie not found error for subtitle '%s'" % (file))
            newPath = os.path.join(mediaFolderPath, "%s.ass" % (movie))
            if movie:
                os.rename(os.path.join(mediaFolderPath, file), newPath)

    print("I have fixed your subtitles!")

fixMySubtitles("/Users/My_User/Desktop/test")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, what should I change in the code (like the directory ?) & also i'm new to python so i don't know what '$' means and other functions. if you could explain it further it would be helpful a lot, thank you in advance :D

Comment: Hey, @VXsz do you mind letting me know whether you are on Mac or Windows?

Comment: Windows 10, Never used Mac btw

Comment: Alright, i've added some comments and i'll just add another section to help you run the method

Comment: I've read it and now it's much better for me to understand, just one last question... should I change "mediaFolderPath" or anything else?

Comment: Ah yes, give me a minute and i'll add instructions at the bottom of the post

Comment: I tried it and it gives me an error "Movie not found error for subtitle 'SUB 01.ass'"... I noticed when I changed my episode name to the same subtitle it goes to the next episode number and repeats the same problem, (btw I'm using test files just so nothing corrupts the original files), also, thank you for the help so far

Comment: Do you have discord or skype by any chance?

Comment: Yes, Discord, but can't use voice

Comment: No problem, it'll be easier to contact and then we can post solution on here

Comment: However do you mind telling me the names of the subtitle and movie files

Comment: i named them "Movie 01.mkv"  "Movie 02.mkv"  "Movie 03.mkv"  "Movie 04.mkv",  and for subs i used "Sub 01.ass" "Sub 02.ass" "Sub 03.ass" "Sub 04.ass"

Comment: Oh then I know the reason why it doesn't work, that's because I thought your subtitles were like 'show-episode.ass' and your files were '[PuyaSubs!]show-episode[1080p].mkv' I thought that the subtitle file would have the episode name in it and the episode would be a longer version of it

Comment: You said that The first file (the anime episode): [PuyaSubs!] Banana Fish - 01 [1080p][EBD2A650].mkv the second (subtitle): Banana Fish - 01.ass could you try with that

Comment: oh, btw my thought was to compare numbers in files names and change the one that matches

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have misunderstood

Comment: Yup, works amazingly

Comment: Glad to hear! I was worried there might be a difference in windows and mac

Comment: Hey if the script works for you, please do consider accepting my answer via the check mark as this will close the thread, otherwise let me know if I can help you anymore!

Comment: So looks like it works :D. but how can I use it in differently named files? (if it's possible), thank you so much., I will try to do some research to understand some functions on the code (for example "$", "%s"... as I see them in a lot of codes,) thanks anyways :D

Comment: It would indeed be possible, however we would still need to maintain one consistent similarity between the subtitle file and the movie file. The current code looks at the subtitle name as a commonality and allows you to search for a movie file with the subtitle name in it. I believe you should be able to modify the code to work with other commonalities such as number. For further research the %s is known as C-style string formatting and it's quite simple yet effective.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution... Assign the variable `inDir` with the path of your files which -I think- is `D:\Downloads\Media\Anime`:

```
import os
import re
from glob import glob

inDir = "D:\Downloads\Media\Anime"

lst = glob(os.path.join(inDir, r"*.ass"))
for filepath in lst:
    parent, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
    episode = re.findall(r"Banana Fish - (\d+).ass", filename)[0]
    newName = "[PuyaSubs!] Banana Fish - {} [1080p][2ECC9207].ass".format(episode)
    os.chdir(parent)
    os.rename(filename, newName)
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work..., I tried modifying the code myself but still, no success... if you have the time can you explain the code

Comment: I edited my code, try it one more time!